# Why the color of System BottomNavigation changes to black when i open bottomsheet?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have set the background color of system bottomNavigation using:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
     getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.navcolor));
}
```

Which is working properly !!!

But the problem is when i open a custom bottomsheet, the background color of bottomNavigation gets changed to black.

Code to show bottomsheet:

```
BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.sortfilterbottomsheet);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog.show();
```

**BottomNavigation when bottomsheet is closed:**
[image]

**BottomNavigation when bottomsheet is opened:**
[image]

Can somebody help ?

Comment: May be bottom sheet overlay. Share screenshot before after...

Comment: @GobuCSG check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I got my answer.

We need to **write**:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/navcolor</item>
```

in **themes.xml** file

It will change the background color of system bottom naivgation.